# Equality of the Covariance of Two Random Variables and the Expected Value of the Product of One and the Difference Between the Other and Its Mean

Tags: covariance, arithmetic

I am trying to understand the second equality in the attached image. Could you please help me by guiding me as to how I can prove this?
Thanks!
[image: Formulae for Estimating Covariance Between Two Random Variables]

Comment: Have you tried expanding $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_{x})(Y-\mu_{y})]$?

Answer (score 1):

If by second equality you mean why is it that
$$E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)] \stackrel{?}{=} E[(X-\mu_X)Y],$$
then consider following @epp's suggestion of expanding $E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]$ to get
\begin{align}
E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)] &= E[(X-\mu_X)Y - (X-\mu_X)\mu_Y],\\
&= E[(X-\mu_X)Y] - E[(X-\mu_X)\mu_Y]\\
&= E[(X-\mu_X)Y] - \mu_YE[X-\mu_X]
\end{align}
which is *very nearly* the equality that is puzzling you.  I wonder what the value of $E[X-\mu_X]$ is....